# Undefined index: string in (...)

Tags: php

I need to switch on E_ALL and get the in the title mentioned warning, when I am exploding the $_GET string:

```
$input = explode( '/', $_GET['string'] );
```

Where does that come from? Is it the missing 3rd parameter (limit) for explode ? I want all entries.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You need to make use of the [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) construct first.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['string'])) {
    $input = explode('/', $_GET['string']);
} else {
    echo "The string was not passed!";
}
```